# Listed selected values from dataset with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to list all columns which contain values 'Unknown' in my pandas data frame. In order to do this I wrote this lines of codes :

```
   for column in dataset.columns:
            if dataset[column].value_counts().values.any():
                print(column)
```

But this piece of code not work well, so can anybody help how to fix this code and listed only columns which contain value 'Unknown' ?

Comment: Is the "Unknown" a string? Can you please post a sample of `dataset`?

Comment: Yes in string format

Comment: What output are you expecting? Your code does literally zero checking for "Unknown".

Comment: Yes here you can find similar dataset https://www.kaggle.com/thomaskonstantin/bank-churn-data-exploration-and-churn-prediction

Comment: Also, why not impute `np.nan` in your data frame then use the standard tools for dealing with nulls?

Comment: I expect to see only columns wich contain values 'Unkown' not other columns

Comment: `[c for c in dataset.columns if any(df[c]=="Unknown")]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for column in dataset.columns:
    if any(dataset[column].isin(['Unknown'])):
        print(f'{column} has the value "Unknown"')
```

Comment: I try this lines of code but receiving this error message : File "<ipython-input-21-d96a8e46c975>", line 3
    print(f'{column} has the value "Unknown")
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Recopy my code, I missed a single quote at the end